# Como implementar timeout no recv() em socket.h

Tags: c, socket

Estou querendo saber se há alguma função para colocar um `timeout` junto com recv() utilizando `Socket.h`.

Exemplo do código:

```
//  Variaveis
UINT    in_socket_handler;
struct  sockaddr_in server;
//  Cria o Socket
in_socket_handler           =   socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,    0);

//
//  Informa para conectar no server
//  IP do servidor
server.sin_family           =   AF_INET;

//  Familia ARPANET
server.sin_addr.s_addr      =   inet_addr(as_host);

//  Porta - hton = host to network short (2bytes) ou htons para mais
server.sin_port             =   htons(an_port);

//  Limpa varivavel
memset  ( &(server.sin_zero), 0x00, sizeof(server.sin_zero));

//  Inicia comunicacao com server
if ( connect(in_socket_handler, (struct sockaddr *) &server,    sizeof (server)) <  0 )
{
    //  Se ocorreu uma falha
    ln_connection_status            =   9;
}
else
{
    //  conectou com sucesso
    ln_connection_status            =   0;
}


// Recebe
int  =  recv( in_socket_handler, buffer, 4096, 0);
```

Alguem sabe se tem alguma forma de receber ate dar time-out, 3 segundos entao junta tudo recebido em uma varivael e retorna?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode usar a função select, descrita aqui:[select(2) - Linux manual](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/select.2.html) e aqui: [windows API select function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx)

Nota: fd = file descriptor, vou chama-lo de descritor

A função select trabalha em cima de vários descritores ao mesmo tempo, ela testa com um timeout se uma determinada operação está disponível nos descritores fornecidos, tais descritores estão contidos em estruturas `fd_set`, esta estrutura é manipulada pelas macros:

`FD_ZERO`: Recebe como parâmetro um fd_set e o inicializa

`FD_SET`: Recebe como parâmetro um descritor(o seu socket) e o insere no fd_set especificado

`FD_ISSET`: Rebece como parametro um descritor e testa se ele está contido no fd_set

A função recebe três fd_set's: o primeiro contem os descritores que serão usados para testar operações de leitura, os descritores do segundo são para testar operações de escrita e os do terceiro para checagem de erros. O primeiro parâmetro da função é um número que indica o maior fd que está contido em todos os fd_set's passados mais um(este é ignorado no windows). O último parâmetro é uma estrutra `timeval` que possui dois campos:

`sec`: o tempo em segundos

`usec`: o tempo em microsegundos

Os dois juntos especificam o tempo que a função deve esperar até que uma operação esteja disponível. Se passar `null` a função irá bloquear até que pelo menos uma operação esteja disponível.

Quando a função retorna os fd_set's passados vão conter apenas os fd's que estão disponíveis para a operação requisitada.

No windows a função está no cabeçalho:`winsock2.h`(lembrando que ele substitui o `winsock.h`), já no linux você deve incluir `sys\select.h` e `sys\time.h`, acho que essas são suficientes, porém o link que informei usa:

```
/* According to POSIX.1-2001 */
#include <sys/select.h>

/* According to earlier standards */
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
    enum OPERATION
    {
        READ = 0,
        WRITE,
        EXCEPTION
    };

    bool testOperation(uint16 sock, OPERATION operation, long milliseconds)
    {
        int r;
        //o primeiro membro da struct é o tempo em segundos e o segundo é o tempo em microsegundos
        struct timeval timeout = { milliseconds/1000, 0};
        fd_set fds;

        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        FD_SET(sock, &fds);

        switch (operation)
        {
        case READ:
            //observe que é possível passar fd_set's nulos
            r = select(sock + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
            break;
        case WRITE:
            r = select(sock + 1, NULL, &fds, NULL, &timeout);
            break;
        case EXCEPTION:
            r = select(sock + 1, NULL, NULL, &fds, &timeout);
            break;
        }

        if (r == SOCKET_ERROR){/*erro*/}

        //operação está disponível
        if (FD_ISSET(sock, &fds))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Este é um código que eu tinha no github mas não usava o timeout, editei agora e não testei o código porque estou no trabalho e aqui não da pra eu testar, mas isso deve funcionar, se não, deve pelo menos te direcionar à resposta.

***EDITED***
Criei dois snippets no github pra demonstrar o uso com dois programas cliente/servidor:

[cliente](https://gist.github.com/shoxsz/e9ff2bd5e99929361e57a4e43222e039)
[servidor](https://gist.github.com/shoxsz/d6a0b035907ad32a8537dffacaa73ed2)

Os dois usam timeout, testei apenas no windows.